# Numerically evaluating $\iiint_{C} \frac{ {\rm d}x \, {\rm d}y \, {\rm d}z}{x^2 +y^2 + z^2}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, multiple-integral

> Numerically evaluate $$\iiint_{C} \frac{ {\rm d}x \, {\rm d}y \, {\rm d}z}{x^2 +y^2 + z^2}$$ where $$C = [-1,1] \times [-1,1] \times [-1,1] = [-1,1]^3$$

---

I do not expect an analytic solution. I would be satisfied with a numeric value. But even this is not so easy.

How to deal with the singularity at the origin? One idea is to first integrate over the unit ball, which can be done analytically, then use monte carlo to integrate over the rest irregular region. But I am not sure whether this will converge fast enough.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use divergence theorem to say

$$\iiint_{[-1,1]^3} \frac{dV}{r^2} = \iint_{\partial [-1,1]^3} \frac{\hat{r}}{r}\cdot\vec{dS}$$

By symmetry we can choose to only integrate over the square in the $z=1$ plane and evaluate

$$\iint_{[-1,1]^2}\frac{6}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}\cos\theta\:dA = \iint_{[-1,1]^2}\frac{6}{x^2+y^2+1}\:dA$$

By even more symmetry we can reduce this to $8$ times an integral over a triangle in the first quadrant

$$\int_0^1\int_0^x \frac{48}{x^2+y^2+1}dydx$$

You can show this is equal to

$$\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}(1)}48\tan^{-1}(\tanh t)\:dt$$

by integrating directly or

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}24\log(\sec^2\theta+1)\:d\theta$$

by integrating in polar coordinates. Numerically these integrals both evaluate to $\approx 15.3482$

Comment: what a masterful calculation!

Comment: @S.Kohn thank you for the kind words!

Comment: Nice! This is a tough one without applying divergence theorem.

Comment: @MathLover thanks! Did you have any other ideas for tackling it? Wolfram never gave an analytic answer for either of those integrals but it would be cool if one existed.

Comment: Letting $u = \mathrm{e}^{-2t}$ in the first integral and using the addition formula for $\arctan$ we can write the result as $24 \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \log(1 + \sqrt{2}) + \operatorname{Ti}_2 (3 - 2 \sqrt{2})] - \mathrm{G} \right)$ with Catalan's constant $\mathrm{G}$ and the [inverse tangent integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html) $\operatorname{Ti}_2$, but a closed-form expression for this particular value of $\operatorname{Ti}_2$ does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a triple integral attempt in spherical coordinates. It does not lead to an analytic answer and I had to evaluate the integral with the help of WolframAlpha.

We consider the cube is made of $8$ unit cubes in $8$ octants. The unit cube in the first octant is bound by,

$x = 0, x = 1, y = 0, y = 1, z = 0,  z= 1$. We again divide this into two parts by plane $x = y$ and integral in the sub-region bound by $y = 0, x = 1, x = y, z = 0, z = 1$ can be evaluated as below using spherical coordinates -

$x = \rho \cos \theta \sin \phi, y = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi, z = \rho \cos \phi$. $x^2+y^2+z^2 = \rho^2$.

$0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$.

**i) when we are bound by plane $z = 1$**

$z = 1 \implies \rho = \sec \phi$

To find the upper bound of $\phi$, let's look at the intersection of plane $z = 1, x = 1$ which is given by,

$\rho = \sec\phi = \sec\theta \csc\phi \implies \phi = \arctan(\sec\theta)$

So, $0 \leq \phi \leq \arctan(\sec\theta)$

$I_1 = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \int_0^{\arctan(\sec\theta)} \int_0^{\sec\phi} \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta \ \approx 0.319755$

**ii) when we are bound by plane $x = 1$**

$x = 1 \implies \rho = \sec \theta \csc \phi$

$\arctan(\sec\theta) \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

$I_2 = \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/4} 
 \int_{\arctan(\sec\theta)}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\sec\theta \csc\phi} \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta \approx 0.639510$

So considering symmetry, the integral over the entire cubic region evaluates to,

$I = 16(I_1 + I_2) \approx 15.348$.

Comment: This isn't correct, and I suspect it's because the symmetries aren't what we'd expect them to be from 2d polar.

Comment: At first I only knew to check the numerical value of what you got on wolfram which does not match the real answer. It's happened to me many times before so what my gut tells me is that the answer being really close is just a coincidence. The problem is that your second region is wrong. When $\phi > \frac{\pi}{4}$ check your upper bound mentally with a picture and you'll see why.

Comment: That is still incorrect. What I mean by upper bound is for the $\rho$. For $\phi \in \left[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ you do not reach the $x=1$ plane immediately, you still touch the $z=1$ plane for some time, dependent on what $\theta$ is. Again the intuition from 2d polar does not carry through, only the picture can save us. Also for the numerical answer it's not an issue of form. A comment proved the answer is extremely transcendental, so there is no way it could be equivalent to something like that.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I had sometime so I at least fixed the integral and once we account for the part of the region I missed last time, it does not lead to an analytic answer as anticipated.